# How to create Category tree using ancestry Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tree, categories, ancestry

I'm trying to make category tree using ancestry Ruby on Rails 3.
My _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@category) do |f| %>
  <% if @category.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@category.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this category from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
        <% @category.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :ancestry %><br />
    <%= f.collection_select :ancestry, Category.all(:order => "title"), :id, :title, :include_blank => true %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

My index.html.erb:

```
<ul id="menu">
  <% for category in @categories %>
    <li><%= link_to h(category.title), category %>
      <%= link_to "subcategory", new_category_path(:parent_id => category) %> |
      <%= link_to "Destroy", category, :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method => :delete %>
      <%= link_to 'Show', category %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

How should I change index to show all category tree?
I was trying to change index to:

```
<ul id="menu">
  <% for category in @categories %>
    <li><%= category.subtree.all(:order => :title, :limit => 10) %>
      <%= link_to "subcategory", new_category_path(:parent_id => category) %> |
      <%= link_to "Destroy", category, :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method => :delete %>
      <%= link_to 'Show', category %>
    </li>       
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

But after change can't see titles just: `#<Category:0xb5fb731c>#<Category:0xb5fb6fc0>`

Comment: Are you asking how to recurse through the category tree to show all children?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you want to display the list of all the categories from the top to the bottom of the tree.

Then using ancestry you have to rely on the `roots` and `children` methods given in the gem.
For instance:

```
<ul id="menu">
  <% Category.roots.each do |category| %>
     <li> <%= link_to h(category.title), category %>
        # depending on the depth of your tree it is better to rely on an helper
        # to drill into the level of the tree
        <% unless category.children.empty? %>
           <ul id="sub-menu"> 
             <% category.children.each do |subcategory| %>
                <li> link_to h(subcategory.title), subcategory </li>
             <% end %>
           </ul>
        <% end %>
     </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

May be you will find the following snippet usefull for the recursive approach:
http://dzone.com/snippets/acts-tree-category-display

Comment: Still I've got some problems. Now I can see names of category but just root and subcategory nothing more. I can see just CategoryLevel1 cant see Level2. 
Root
-CategoryLevel1
--CategoryLevel2

Comment: @user1502296 - Well the code above, just display the root and the first layer of children. If you want a recursive version go and look at the snippets I pasted above.